# Energy distorting space

Tags: space-travel, warp-drives

We know that mass distort space and time. Can energy do the same? How much heat will it take to create an observable effect? can we make a warp drive on that principle? By heating one end of a space ship to insane temperatures to create distort space and creating sort of a wave on which a ship can travel kindly keep the language simple I am just a physics enthusiast.

Comment: This isn't directly related to heating the ship, but you should check out this wikipedia page if you haven't already: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it can do the same! The realization is pretty simple: Mass and energy... Are the same thing! So basically, whatever property you can assign to mass, you can assign to energy as well. The more 'physical' intuition of it comes from Einstein's arch-famous formula $E=mc^2$.

Now, heat is not energy so 'How much heat will it take to create an observable effect' is not the right question to ask... And definitely you can't just heat one end of a ship to create such an effect. However, there are some proposals of motors that 'contract' space in front of a ship that could theoretically achieve light-like travel... But the understandment of those goes way beyond my knowledge (a just-graduated physicist) so definitely beyond that of an enthusiast too... But hope you see things clearer now :)